# Remove from a std::set<shared_ptr<T>> by T*

Tags: c++, boost, smart-pointers

I have a set of shared pointers:

```
std::set<boost::shared_ptr<T>> set;
```

And a pointer:

```
T* p;
```

I would like to *efficiently* remove the element of `set` equal to `p`, but I can't do this with any of the members of set, or any of the standard algorithms, since `T*` is a completely different type to `boost::shared_ptr<T>`.

A few approaches I can think of are:

- somehow constructing a new shared_ptr from the pointer that won't take ownership of the pointed to memory (ideal solution, but I can't see how to do this)
- wrapping / re-implementing shared_ptr so that I can do the above
- just doing my own binary search over the set

Comment: Why do you have this raw T pointer anyway?

Comment: Why not? I often find myself with smart pointers in the `Factory` class and only raw pointers / references outside. The outside need not know how I manage my objects.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Construct a `shared_ptr<T>` from `T` with a `null_deleter` (see [boost:::shared_ptr FAQ](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/smart_ptr/sp_techniques.html#static)).

```
struct null_deleter {
    void operator()(void const *) const { }
};

size_t remove_ptr_from_set(std::set<boost::shared_ptr<T>> &set, X* x)
{
    shared_ptr<X> px(x, null_deleter());
    return set.erase(px);
}
```

That way the types are compatible and you don't have to worry about your temporary shared_ptr deleting any object.

Or, as one of the comments say, if you can change T to inherit from [enable_shared_from_this](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/smart_ptr/enable_shared_from_this.html) you could get a correct shared ptr from your object.

Comment: +1 Darn, was about to post this. I dismissed it at first due to (wrong) idea that the deleter was part of the `shared_ptr` type.

Comment: There is actually a separate FAQ for obtaining a `shared_ptr` from `this` in the FAQ linked in this answer. There appears to be a class template called `enable_shared_from_this` that, when inherited, provides a `weak_ptr` to `this`. See http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/smart_ptr/enable_shared_from_this.html.

Comment: @Space_C0wb0y: True. However, it depends if you can change T to inherit that. Not always possible.

Comment: I had some trouble using a shared_ptr with a null deleter: set::count returns zero even when there is a shared_ptr in the set with the same address as the one I construct... so I'm going for the `enable_shared_from_this` solution instead.

Comment: @Autopopulated: Strange! The == and < operators for shared_ptr are defined in terms of the address only. (I just checked)

Answer (score 1):

If the reason for using the set is that you need to efficiently find pointers of type T, then the obvious answer is not to make it a set of shared pointers! Instead, wrap the set in a class which manages the lifetimes of the pointers that the set contains.

Comment: composition over inheritance!

Comment: That seems like a large amount of work compared to the other options (that's why I didn't list it!): the _only_ time I need to lookup by pointer rather than shared_ptr is when I'm removing objects (and objects might persist beyond removal until the last user's shared_ptr is destroyed), so I can't blindly tie the lifespan of objects to their being in the container.

Comment: @Eric - not really. `std::set<boost::shared_ptr<T>>` is already composition, not inheritance. Neil is suggesting composing the right things, instead of composing the wrong things.

Comment: @Dan - I know, i just wanted to point out that the solution isn't with inheritance

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`boost::ptr_set`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_set.html) if you want the set to have ownership of the objects, or [`boost::reference_wrapper`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/doc/html/ref.html) if you just want the set to store references to them. If you use `shared_ptr` in one place in your code, you will have to use it in all places, or risk terrible crashes (dangling pointers, already deleted objects etc.). The exception is [`weak_ptr`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/smart_ptr/weak_ptr.htm), a pointer that points to an object held by a `shared_ptr` but does not share ownership.

Comment: The set is one owner of the objects, but others users may persist after they are removed from the set, so `boost::ptr_set` is not appropriate.
For this reason also I can't use the `reference_wrapper` or `weak_ptr`, since in both cases users may be left with dangling references.

Comment: Using pointers also has the risk of, well, dangling pointers. Why can you not remove the objects using a `shared_ptr`? Why do you introduce a normal pointer there?

Comment: effectively I want to remove from within a member function of the objects stored, so somewhere higher up the stack there is a shared_ptr referring to the object, but I don't want to have to pass it down when the `this` pointer is readily available. Basically I want to do: `removeFromSet(this)`